# Removing duplicate rows in mysql and keeping new entries

Tags: mysql, duplicates

I am quite new to StackOverflow, have been searching for the solution, but found only partial answers. So let me explain my problem.

In my company we migrated from old to new server LAST WEEK. This included migration of main business application on MySQL 5.0 to newer MariaDB 10.0. The database has 70 GB of data and more than 5000 tables with 0-50000 rows each. 
By my opinion programmers of business app are using some weird approach to table creation, and obviously each new report or relation has new table.

Tables are all MyISAM.

Now, we had to migrate on our own, prepared MariaDB like we should, everyting fine. And everyting would be fine, if...
**...if we wouldn't accidentally run MySQL copy twice!** 
Nobody knows how this happened, but approximately 500 out of 5000 tables have exactly 2-times row count in new MariaDB compared to old MySQL.

And this still wouldn't be a problem, if we'd notice it immediately. But we didn't. We noticed the problem only today, 7 days after migration and some 10000 bills already sent and processed, 50 paychecks issued etc.

So, now we have:
- OLD database, 7 days old, with non-duplicated data
- NEW database, with a lot of changes, but with 10% of tables with duplicate rows

Some of those duplicated table rows have "*timestamp*" column, so theoretically we could export only changes, done after last monday...
...but some of duplicated rows in some tables do NOT have "*timestamp*", so we cannot know, which rows have been added or changed since last monday.

If I announce to my boss that people would need to re-enter all changes from past week, I guess he will kill me at least once.
Any idea of some approach to solve the situation with least pain?

Comment: A time machine certainly helps

Comment: Oh, yes... how on earth I did not think of it...

Comment: Yeah I know -- it can be kind of expensive to buy one, unfortunately :(